# gradle maven-publish publishMavenWebPublicationToRemoteArtifactoryRepository

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

I'm using the gradle maven-publish plugin.

gradlew tasks

Publishing tasks

> ---
>
> generatePomFileForMavenWebPublication - Generates the Maven POM file for publication 'mavenWeb'.
>
> publish - Publishes all publications produced by this project.
>
> publishMavenWebPublicationToMavenLocal - Publishes Maven publication 'mavenWeb' to the local Maven repository.
>
> publishMavenWebPublicationToRemoteArtifactoryRepository - Publishes Maven publication 'mavenWeb' to Maven repository 'remoteArtifactory'.
>
> publishToMavenLocal - Publishes all Maven publications produced by this project to the local Maven cache.

I'd like to execute the 'assemble' task before 'publishMavenWebPublicationToRemoteArtifactoryRepository':

> publishMavenWebPublicationToRemoteArtifactoryRepository.dependsOn assemble

However, I get an error:

> Could not find property 'publishMavenWebPublicationToRemoteArtifactoryRepository' on root project 'MyProject'?

Any idea on how to ensure 'publishMavenWebPublicationToRemoteArtifactoryRepository' depends on 'assemble'?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

```
publish {
  dependsOn assemble 
}
```

this should work